# I want to get the ID of the pdf page input tag of chrome

Tags: html, pdf

I opened pdf using selenium. After that, I want to get the ID of the input tag that enters the page .

[image]

```
# file_name = pdf
def set_page(file_name):
    path = './edgedriver_win32/msedgedriver.exe'
    browser = webdriver.Edge(path)
    browser.get(file_name)
    element = browser.find_element_by_id('pageselector')
    browser.close()
```

Comment: What's wrong with the code you've posted?

Comment: When you try to get an ID for that pageselector, the error "Selenium.common.exception.NoSuchElementException" appears.